# Kinda new to Java and stuck with collections. Here I'm trying to generate random numbers without duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my snippet. record[i] is an object with 2 variables id and number. And I'm getting the error unexpected type : required variable; found : value.

```
int Shuffle = 0;
List<Integer> randomID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> randomNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0;i<100 ;i++) {
    randomID.add(new Integer(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(randomID);

for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    randomNumber.add(new Integer(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(randomNumber);

for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    if (randomID.contains(record[i].ID)) {
        randomID.indexOf(record[i].ID)=null; //ERROR : REQUIRED VARIABLE FOUND VALUE
    }
}
for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    if (randomNumber.contains(record[i].getNumber())) {
        randomNumber.indexOf(record[i].getNumber())=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that ID should be in all caps?  Could you show the Record class?  That would help me to find the problem.

Comment: I don't see any random number generated here. Use `Random.nextInt(100)` which gives you a random number between 0-100.

Comment: @Eranda He is using the shuffle method to make the ID's random.

Comment: class Record
{
    public int ID;
    private int accountNumber,balance;
    private String name,password; ..... }

Comment: I don't think randomNumber (which is shuffled) is used in the part where he's referring to to be thrown an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to randomID.indexOf(record[i].ID) returns some value.  You have put it on the left side of an equals sign, so the compiler is looking for something to which it can ASSIGN a value.  It can't assign a value to a value, it must have a variable.

I suppose you might mean to assign null to the ID of that element of the array: `record[i].ID = null;`

Or you might need the index into randomID:

```
int index = randomID.indexOf(record[i].ID);
randomID.set(index, null);
```

but you end up with a list that has a bunch of nulls in it. Is that really what you want?

Anyway, your question was about the error.  If you have a different question, ask it in a different post.

Comment: Understood that im getting the index from the previous statement and trying to assign it null....my bad haha

Comment: One more question....If i use sets and if i change two values to be null, will the second one be ignored ? That actually is better than a list with lot of nulls right ?

Comment: If what you want to do is remove the element that you found, just use remove and be done with it.  You can remove an element from a set; just make sure you don't do it in a loop where you are iterating through the set (which you're not doing here -- you're iterating through a group of numbers and then indexing into the set, which is ok for removing from the set).

Answer (score 0):

With java collections, there are several types of storage.
The List collection allows for duplicate entries.
The Set collection does not allow duplicates.

```
Set  set = new HashSet<Integer>(); //assuming you want Integer
int randomNumberCount = 10
while(set.size() < randomNumberCount) {
    int temp = Math.random() * 100;
    set.add(new Integer(temp));
}
```

Adding entries to a set that already exist will just replace it.